# Manually instantiate a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

Is it possible to use a data template for a single item with no ListBox or other items control?

I have a datatemplate that I want to instantiate in xaml, not in a list, just within a border, and set its datacontext.

Something like (pseudo):

```
<Window DataContext="{StaticResource Contact}">
    <!--
        Here I want to show a ContactTemplate for a single Contact
        as it would appear in an ItemsControl (ListBox etc.)
    -->
    <src:ContactTemplate Source="{Binding}"/>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentControl` to a `DataTemplate`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: To spell it out more explicitly: <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContactTemplate}" />.

Comment: Thank you for the respelling, it was indeed necessary.

Comment: Is ContentConrol->ContentTempate the thinnest type to which I can apply DataTemplate?

Comment: Actually, a ContentPresenter is.  And if your DataTemplate is specified solely with a DataType and not a key, you don't even have to specify the template on the ContentPresenter.  It's implicit. This is actually how ItemsControld already work.  They use a ContentPresenter as part of their ContainerItem's ControlTemplate.  It's the ContentPresenter that's actually doing the template-related work.